# Dynamic dropdown list using JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

I want to make a dynamic drop-down list based on a JavaScript object like this:

```
var EXERCISE_OBJ = {
    "title" : {
        "name" : "Exercise_Name",
        "category" : "Pronunciation",
        "type":"Multiple Choice",
        },

    "title2" : {
        "name" : "Exercise_Name2",
        "category" : "Spelling",
        "type":"Crossword",
        },

   "title3" : {
        "name" : "Exercise_Name3",
        "category" : "Spelling",
        "type":"Multiple Choice",
        },

   "title4" : {
        "name" : "Exercise_Name4",
        "category" : "Grammar",
        "type":"Wordsearch",
        },
}
```

I want a drop-down list enlisting all the categories and another one displaying all the exercise titles from each category.. How can I output it?

Comment: Yay! you have a bunch of objects you want to do something with, but haven't bothered to try _anything_.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Create div with id test. <div id="test"></div>

 var exercise_select = "<select name='exc'>";
 var category_select = "<select name='cate'>";

  $.each(EXERCISE_OBJ, function() {
             var name = this.name;
             var category = this.category;
             exercise_select += "<option value='"+name+"'>"+name+"</option>";
             category_select += "<option value='"+category+"'>"+category+"</option>";
});
   exercise_select += "</select>";       category_select += "</select>";                     
     $("#test").append(exercise_select);        $("#test").append(category_select);
```